# Need help finishing a Python grading program

Tags: python, average, if-statement, assignment-operator

I want to create a python program that does the following:

1. Ask the user for the number of tests, assignments, quizzes, and labs in their 
   course.
2. Ask the user if there is a final with a separate weight from the tests above, e.g. a 
   course has 2 tests, each weighing 12.5%, and 1final weighing 15%.
3. For each category having a number > 0 
   a. Prompt the user for the weighted percent, out of 100%, which should total 
   100% for all categories!!! 
   b. Get the score(s) for the category. 
   c. If the category is labs, then sum all the scores. 
   d. Else, average the scores. 
   e. Calculate the weighted average for the category.
4. Using the weighted average of each category, calculate the grade in the course.
5. Ask the user if he/she wants to calculate a grade for another class.
6. If the user responds yes, then go back to step 1.
7. Else, end the program.

What I have so far is the input portion:

```
tests = raw_input("Enter the number of tests in course: ")
tests = int
assignments = raw_input("Enter the number of assignments in course: ")
quizzes = raw_input("Enter the number of quizzes in course: ")
labs = raw_input("Enter the number of labs in course: ")
sepweightfinal = raw_input("Is there a final with a separate weight? ")
```

When I try to do anything after input I can't get it to work.

Such as if tests > 0 percent = input("What is the weighted percent of tests?: ")

My program always says that > and 0 is invalid, is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance, basically I understand the logic and what I want to accomplish, the code just isn't clicking in my head.

Comment: Can you post *all* of your code?

Comment: Is this homework for a class assignment?

Comment: This is unfortunately all that I have. I'm a newbie to python. After the input portion I tried to add "If tests > 0 raw_input("Enter the weighted percent of tests: ") How would I go about doing that for each section?

Comment: @Jim yes it is. Our prof basically lets us figure out how to do the assignment without any real explanation in class. Most inclass lecture is geared towards flowcharts and psuedocode as well as having software engineers speak to us. Having never done python programming I find it hard to just jump right in.

Comment: Don't go straight to code. Design your program, work out the logical small steps needed - break down each one of your 1-7 steps into smaller and smaller steps until you can't simplify then any further. Then start looking at turning each one into code.  Learn to flow chart

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string returned by `raw_input()` into an integer using `int`:

```
tests_string = raw_input("Enter the number of tests in course: ")
tests = int(tests_string)
```

Or more concisely:

```
tests = int(raw_input("Enter the number of tests in course: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable for weighted percentage for eg

```
if test>0:
    test_weight=float(raw_input("Enter the weight of the tests:")
else:
    test_weight=0
if assignments>0:
    assign_weight=float(raw_input("Enter the weight of the assignments:")
else:
    assign_weight=0
```

Then chk if the sum of all the weights is equal to 100

```
if (test_weight+assign_weight+lab_weight+final_weight)!=100:
    print "The weights are not accurate"
    break
```

Use floats for obtaining the scores of each one and a for loop for the number of test.

```
for i in range(0,test):
    test_score.append(float(raw_input("Enter the score for the test:")))
```

Where test_score is a list.Now that you have lists for all the scores of different components of the scores you can compute the sum,avg etc with them and calculate the grade finally using if statement.

```
if weightedavg>=60:
    grade='A'
elif weightedavg>=40:
    grade='B'
else:
    grade='C'
```

Put the whole thing in a while loop

```
while(1):
```

and break the loop if user reponds no for point 6

```
if user_resp=='N':
    print "Goodbye"
    break
```

For better readability instead of having many variable i would suggest you to put all the data into a dict with keys as the different components of the course.It would be much easier to handle organized stuff.

Comment: With this you must be able to write your own code as I have given example for each and every part of the code.Moreover you dont just ask for the complete code over here.Search the internet and if you still have doubts or if the code is giving errors you can ask it.This isnt the place for "I am not able to write it can someone do it for me,Please".

Comment: Thank you for your help, your explanation will help me greatly. I'm sorry if it seemed like I wanted all of the code for a complete program, I'm just new to programming and I don't know how to do any of this. Any google search was basically general concepts with little application to this program. Learning when the process is explained is extremely helpful =)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
tests = int(raw_input(" Enter the number of tests in course: "))
```